# How do I update an existing state object without infinite redirects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const useExample = (something) => {
   const [v, setV] React.useState(something)
   React.useEffect(() => setV({...v ...something), [something, v, setV])
}
```

This code above runs an infinite loop because I am using `v` to set `v`. How can I set v to a value using `v` but not cause this loop?

Comment: Split the injected useEffect dependencies into different useEffect calls.

Comment: Why not just do: `React.useEffect(() => setV({...v ...something), [something])` Are you using `setV` in other places?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument in the `useEffect` handles the rerendering of the function. The answer to your question since it is quite generic would be to use an empty array.

```
const useExample = (something) => {
   const [v, setV] React.useState(something)
   React.useEffect(() => setV({...v ...something), [])
}
```

But that depends on the condition you want to set... Tell you the truth, I am kinda confused about your case. Could you give more info...??

The example you are giving is quite problematic. Why are you spreading the initalValue?? And why would you set the v as the rerendering option??

Answer (score 0):

The pattern used is to have a flag to do the update whenever you need that change to occur.

```
  const [v, setV] = React.useState(something)
  const [flagV, setFlagV] = React.useState(something)
   React.useEffect(() => {
      if (flagV){ 
       setV({...v ...something);
       setFlagV(false)
         }
}, [something,v,setV,flagV,setFlagV])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there may be a better solution to your problem if I know why you'd combine props with state.

It looks like you're trying to create a function that combines the argument previously passed to it with the argument currently passed to it letting current override last properties. If that is the case then there is a much simpler way of doing this.

With the information provided so far you can prevent the infinite loop by memoizing props (called `something` in your method) and `v` and have that memoized function set the merged result:

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';

const Something = something => {
  const [v, setV] = useState(something);
  //memoize setting merged
  const merged = useMemo(() => {
    return { ...v, ...something };
  }, [something, v]);
  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(merged)}
      {/* can still set v  */}
      <button onClick={() => setV({ other: 22 })}>
        Add other
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default () => {
  const [p, setP] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      {/* change the props passed to Something */}
      <button onClick={() => setP(p + 1)}>UP</button>
      <Something prop={p} />
    </div>
  );
};
```